# unable to run program via eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am getting error whenever running java program via selenium.

**my code :**

```
package mTash;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Celebrity {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
        driver.get("https://www.mariatash.com/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
}
}
```

**error:**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-6', revision: '5f43a29cfc'
System info: host: 'SUFIYAAN', ip: '192.168.43.107', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:105)
    at mTash.Celebrity.main(Celebrity.java:13)
```

CAN ANY1 help me out.

Comment: Your driver fails to start. Add two more properties before `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` which are: `webdriver.chrome.logfile` with the value where driver will be posting its logs, `webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging` with the value `true`. Then check for a clue at the produced log file.

Comment: This may be because of  incorrect chromedriver version. Check your current chrome browser version (open chrome--> help--> about Google chrome-->check version) and then download the same chromedriver and provide path.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine,

1. Check whether you have correct chrome version and chromedriver version
2. Click on the top menu bar > project > clean
3. Click windows>show view>others > problems , and see if there any problems in your code